# Display output of a switch statement in a span tag in php wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to display the switch statement result in a span tag. After applying switch conditions when I use echo within span tag it displays nothing. But when I only use echo after switch conditions the result is displayed.

How can i display switch statement result within a particular span tag?

```
public static function woocommerce_template_after_single_rating() {
    global $product;

    switch (    $stock_status = $product->get_shipping_class()) {
       case 'immediate':
           $stock_status = 'In Stock';
           break;

       case 'custom':
          $stock_status = 'Bespoke product';
          break;

       case 'international':
         $stock_status = 'special product';
         break;

       default:
         $stock_status = 'unknown';
   }
   ?> 
    <div class="woocommerce-product-details__stock">
        <span class="stock" <?php echo $stock_status; ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line (you forgot the closing `>` for the span tag):

```
            <span class="stock" <?php echo $stock_status; ?></span>
```

This will actually produce something like..

```
<span class="stock" In Stock</span>
```

Fix it by really adding it within the span:

```
<span class="stock"><?php echo $stock_status; ?></span>
```

Also, I would advise against modifying the switched variable inside the switch statement - this isn't particularly clean code.

Comment: The thing is: since you posted only an incomplete part of the code, I cannot guess where things go wrong. The code in your post misses the closing curly bracket `}` for the `woocommerce_template_after_single_rating` function (and the PHP tag before that). Also, since I have no idea where or how that callback function is used, there's no way to identify the problem. Is it hooked on a filter or action?

Comment: its action hook                                                                                         add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'woocommerce_template_after_single_rating' ), 11 );

Comment: public static function woocommerce_template_after_single_rating() {
  global $product;

  $availability = $product->get_availability();

  ?>
   <div class="woocommerce-product-details__stock">
    <span class="stock <?php echo esc_attr( $availability['class'] ); ?>"><?php echo 'in stock' === $availability['class'] ? esc_html_e( 'in stock', 'woondershop-pt' ) : esc_html_e( 'Out of stock', 'woondershop-pt' ); ?></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <?php
 }

Comment: the above code where i want to display stock status based on shipping classes within this span tag. i have used switch statement but it dont work

Comment: Your problem is here: `add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'woocommerce_template_after_single_rating' ), 11 );`

When using a **static method** as a callback, do not use `$this` when adding the hook. Instead, use the class name like so:
`add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( static::class, 'woocommerce_template_after_single_rating' ), 11 );`